# Confidence interval related to $\max X_i$ and $\min X_i$ if iid continuous random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, statistical-inference, confidence-interval

I am trying to solve the following exercise:

Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be iid continuous random variables with density function given by $f(x)$. Let $M$ be the median of the $X's$ distributions, that means, $P(X_i \leq M)=\dfrac{1}{2}$ for all $i$.

a) Show that $P(\max X_i< M \cup \min X_i > M)=\dfrac{1}{2^{n-1}}$.

b) Deduce that $(\min X_i, \max X_i)$ is a confidence interval for $M$ of level $1-\dfrac{1}{2^{n-1}}$.

This is what I could do:

Using the fact that given two events $A,B$, $P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B)$, we have 
$$P(\max X_i< M \cup \min X_i > M)=P(\max X_i < M)+P(\min X_i > M)+P(\max X_i < M \cap \min X_i >M)\\
=P(X_1<M,...,X_n<M)+P(X_1>M,...,X_n>M)+0\\
=\dfrac{1}{2^n}+\dfrac{1}{2^n}=\dfrac{1}{2^{n-1}}.$$

I am completely stuck in b), I don't know what to do to deduce b) from a). I would appreciate some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are given that $$P(\max X_i< M\ \text{or}\ \min X_i > M)=\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$$ and you are asking why $$P(M\in[\min X_i,\max X_i])=1-\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$$ Well, the reason is that $$[\max X_i< M\ \text{or}\ \min X_i > M]^c=[\min X_i\leqslant M\ \text{and}\ M\leqslant\max X_i]=[M\in[\min X_i,\max X_i]]$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Did!